# link viewmodel to view

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I can't get my xaml to bind with my viewmodel. I have in my viewModel a ObservableCollection of a INotifyPropertyChanged class that holds data about a recepie.  Here is my Recepie class :

```
namespace WP7SQLiteClient.Model
{
    public class MainViewModelItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string _title, _subTitle, _imageUriPath;

        string title
        {

            get
            {
                return _title;
            }
            set
            {
                _title = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("title");
            }
        }
        string subTitle
        {
            get
            {
                return _subTitle;
            }
            set
            {
                _subTitle = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("subTitle");
            }
        }
        string imageUriPath
        {
            get
            {
                return _imageUriPath;
            }
            set
            {
                _imageUriPath = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("imageUriPath");
            }
        }

        public MainViewModelItem(string title, string subtitle, string imageuripath)
        {
            this.title = title;
            this.subTitle = subtitle;
            this.imageUriPath = imageuripath;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my ViewModel which holds the list of recepies :

```
namespace WP7SQLiteClient.ViewModel
{

        public class PanoramaViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public ObservableCollection<MainViewModelItem> _recepiesList;


            public ObservableCollection<MainViewModelItem> recepiesList
            {
                get
                {
                    return _recepiesList;
                }

                set
                {
                    _recepiesList = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("recepiesList");
                }
            }

            public PanoramaViewModel()
            {
                this.recepiesList = new ObservableCollection<MainViewModelItem>();

            }

            public bool IsDataLoaded
            {
                get;
                private set;
            }

            public void LoadData()
            {
                this.recepiesList.Add(new MainViewModelItem("Classics", "", ""));
                this.recepiesList.Add(new MainViewModelItem("Perfect Pasta", "", ""));
                this.recepiesList.Add(new MainViewModelItem("Favorites", "", ""));
                this.recepiesList.Add(new MainViewModelItem("Snacks & Antipasti", "", ""));
                this.recepiesList.Add(new MainViewModelItem("Desserts", "", ""));
                this.recepiesList.Add(new MainViewModelItem("3 minutes recipes", "", ""));

                this.IsDataLoaded = true;
            }


            private string _sampleProperty = "Sample Runtime Property Value";
            /// <summary>
            /// Sample ViewModel property; this property is used in the view to display its value using a Binding
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public string SampleProperty
            {
                get
                {
                    return _sampleProperty;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (value != _sampleProperty)
                    {
                        _sampleProperty = value;
                        NotifyPropertyChanged("SampleProperty");
                    }
                }
            }




            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
                }
            }
        }

}
```

In my MainPage.xaml (it's in the root of the project, the viewModel is in the ViewModel folder and the Model is in the Model folder) i have my listbox declared like this :

```
<ListBox x:Name="recepiesList"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewModelTemplate}" > 

                </ListBox>
```

The template is located in the App.xaml and is correct for sure. It uses things like `{Binding title}`

In the MainPage.cs i try to link the view model with the page using :

```
public static PanoramaViewModel viewModel = null;

        public static PanoramaViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                // Delay creation of the view model until necessary
                if (viewModel == null)
                    viewModel = new PanoramaViewModel();

                return viewModel;
            }
        } 
public MainPage()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            ViewModel.LoadData();
            DataContext = ViewModel;

        }
```

But it doesn't work, nor the debugger raises an error. How can i correctly link the viewmodel with the xaml ?

**UPDATE** my template looks like this :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewModelTemplate"> <!-- for recent recepies-->

            <Grid Width="400" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Border CornerRadius="0" x:Name="brdTesat" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="80" Height="80">

                    <Border.Background>
                        <ImageBrush x:Name="backgroundImaageBrush" Stretch="Fill">

                            <ImageBrush.ImageSource>

                                    <BitmapImage x:Name="bmapBackground" UriSource="{Binding imageUriPath}" >
                                </BitmapImage>

                            </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                        </ImageBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                </Border>
                    <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left" Margin="7,4,4,4" Text="{Binding title}" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left" Margin="7,4,4,4" Text="DA" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

**UPDATE 2**

i've changed my listbox code to :

```
<ListBox x:Name="recepiesList"  ItemsSource="{Binding recepiesList}" >             </ListBox>
```

With no template, i get a list of `[project_name].Model.MainViewModelItem`, so i think there is a problem with the template.. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind you ListBox to the data. So, this should work for you.

```
<ListBox x:Name="recepiesList" ItemsSource="{Binding recepiesList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewModelTemplate}"  />
```

Comment: doesn't work.. i get : A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'title' property not found on 'WP7SQLiteClient.Model.MainViewModelItem' 'WP7SQLiteClient.Model.MainViewModelItem' (HashCode=65782377

Comment: i.e. the subTitle string doesn't appear because i am not binding it, i give it a static string

Comment: Because properties of your viewmodel aren't public! Make them public and be happy :)

Comment: ah you are right about the public, but i still don't have anything showing

Comment: no error, but not showing the items in the listbox.. no errors in the output

Comment: Get Snoop and check if there are any ListBoxItem is rendered in the ListBox. Also, show your template and update code snippets with public properties. Because it's hard to say what is the issue if you have no binding errors in output.

Comment: i've added an UPDATE2, please look

Comment: The problem was the template, tnx!

Answer (score 0):

We're using MEF in a project and we link the view models up with the following code in the View.xaml.cs:

```
[Import]
public ConnectionStringSetupViewModel ViewModel
{
    get { return DataContext as ConnectionStringSetupViewModel; }
    set { DataContext = value; }
}
```

This allows the import to be satisfied when the catalogs are created.  If you aren't using MEF, you can use the same code above without the import, but when your view is created you'll have to assign a new instance of your viewmodel class to it.

Comment: How can i assign a new instance of my viewmodel class ? i'm not sure what you mean

Comment: PanaromaView p = new PanaromaView();
p.ViewModel = new PanaromaViewModel();

Comment: i've added an UPDATE2, please look

Comment: That's exactly what you will get without the template assigned.  I think once you combine both the ItemsSource and the ItemsTemplate you'll be where you need to be.